# rewrite rule in next js for image address

Tags: image, next.js

I'm using next/image so in ssr pages and next server, it gets image from address like this:

"http://inner-server-ip/img/pic1.png"

so next changes it to

"/_next/image?url=http://inner-server-ip/img/pic1.png",

what i want is to hide "http://inner-server-ip" in client side browser(for security reason), so i tried to use rewrite rule(somthing like if my url starts with /img then append server to it) but figure it out it not works on image optimization route, or i'm wrong, is there any way for what i want to do?

Comment: There is no way to completely hide your source IP from the user, there will always be a way to figure it out, especially if you are just rewriting the URL. This is **not** a security concern in any way.

Comment: if my images hosted in same location of next server that was fine but now it hosted in backend server, so thats the issue

Comment: Still not really a problem, just properly protect whatever sensitive information you have on your "backend server" or use something like a Amazon S3 bucket and host your images externally.

Comment: problem is fixed, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for people that want to do this, you can create rewrite rule on middleware with more flexible coding capability, so

1- i first removed server ip(or addr) from src in order to it be a relative address

2- then put my condition for a rewrirte rule in middleware of next js, something like this:

```
if(~req.url.indexOf("_next/image?url=%2Fbackend_img%2F")){
    const idx = url.indexOf("%2Fbackend_img%2F")
    const newUrl = `/_next/image?url=${backendIp}${req.url.slice(idx)}`;
    return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL(newUrl, req.url))
}
```

so when request comes like this:

```
"_next/image?url=/backend_img/sample.png"
```

it will rewtite to this in sever:

```
"_next/image?url=${backendIp}/backend_img/sample.png"
```